# Ionic Framework - View on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, ionic-framework, emulation

I need to display my ionic application on my iPhone.

I have developed the application within the www folder and have used the command "ionic serve -l" to test my app in safari.

I now need to demonstrate my application on my phone. However, when I upload my application to the "ionic view" app it does not display in the same format on my phone, prior to when I have been testing in the browser.

Can somebody please shed some light in how I may solve this issue..

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Use `ionic run android` or `ionic run ios` to run your application on a connected device or emulator. Read more about it here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html, http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html